# Tab bar item transition

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I have a tab bar controller in my code and I want to make the transition with animation between the tab bar items. I found a way to do this with the controllers, but not with the items. I know I have to use UIView.animate, but I don't know how. Any ideas?

Comment: What animation do you wish to see? All of the tab bar items are visible so there is no need for any kind of fade between the items.

Comment: A animate transitivos beetwen the Tab items. I can do this?

Comment: Your question is not clear. What exactly do you want to do differently from a standard UITabBar when you click on a different tab?

Comment: I have an image indicator in the top of the Tab bar items, and when a change the item, a wanna an animation in this image.

Comment: Sorry for my English. I'm from Brazil

Comment: Your English is fine. But you may be interested in [Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I have a tabBarController with some tabBar items,when I click the item,it‘s scale will larger and then back to default size,it just looks as an animation.
With `Objective-C` you can use as follows :

```
//didSelectItem

-(void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item{

        NSInteger index = [self.tabBar.items indexOfObject:item];
        [self animationWithIndex:index];
    }



//animation 

- (void)animationWithIndex:(NSInteger) index {
    NSMutableArray *tabBarBtnArr = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (UIView *tabBarBtn in self.tabBar.subviews) {
        if ([tabBarBtn isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UITabBarButton")]) {
            [tabBarBtnArr addObject:tabBarBtn];
        }

    }
    UIButton *btn=tabBarBtnArr[index];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
        btn.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.2, 1.2);

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
            btn.transform=CGAffineTransformIdentity;

        }];
    }];

}
```

Comment: I think I will animate the controllers only, but thanks!

Comment: You just want to make a animation between the  different viewControllers of the tabBarController ?

Comment: No, I wanna in the Tab bar index